# cross-signing with OpenSSL

Tags: openssl, signing, ca

I need to create two self-signed Certificate Authorities (that would belong to different people), and then cross-sign them, so the certificates emitted would be trusted by both.

However, surprisingly, I can't find any documentation on how to do so with OpenSSL.

The interwebs have a couple of (already dead) scripts that explain cross-signing, but I havent been able to dig them up, either.

So, anybody with OpenSSL CA experience here? :)

Comment: General concept: There is a field in the certificate that says whether this is a certificate authority. In the default settings, this field is forced to "no", and usually the "critical" bit set as well. You want to set it to "yes" -- otherwise this is a regular certification. Not an answer as I don't give a HOWTO.

Comment: Well, of course the CA:true is set. How would I use those certs as CA otherwise? :)